# Force axios to return a cached response using axios-cache-interceptor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, caching, axios

How to force axios to return a cached response using axios-cache-interceptor?

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { setupCache } from 'axios-cache-interceptor'

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  timeout: 60 * 1000 // 1 minute.
})

export const httpClient = setupCache(axiosInstance)

httpClient.get('https://example-api.dev')
```

Comment: It should do so automatically for any repeated requests.  there is nothing special you need to do.  what is your use case where you are not seeing this behavior?

Comment: @yoduh It returns cached responses when navigating within the app. However, refreshing the page sends a new request, which is not what I want. Interestingly, everything works exactly as expected in offline mode.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it should work automatically.

Except one thing missing: in order to use the response, you should/could `await` or `then` the value fetched.
I understand it will return the fetched data for the first time. Afterwards it will consistently return the cached data for that requested URL.

> How it works
>
> By using axios interceptors instead of adapters, each request is
> passed through the interceptor before calling the adapter and before
> returning to the original caller. Adapters are the final step and they
> are responsible for the actual network call, so, by choosing to use
> interceptors, we create a minimally invasive approach that allows you
> to still use the axios adapter of your choice.
>
> Before the request is delivered to the adapter, our request
> interceptor checks if the request have already been cached and if it’s
> a valid one, checks if the request should be cached (sometimes you
> don’t want cache at all, and it’s ok), if there’s already a request
> sent to the network that we can wait for it and many more other
> checks.
>
> After the adapter gets the response, we check if it belongs to a
> cacheable request, saves it into the storage, resolves other requests
> awaiting for the same resource and finally returns the response to the
> original caller.

Source: https://axios-cache-interceptor.js.org/guide

Comment: See my comment above. Replacing Memory Storage with Web Storage API solves the issue. "A memory storage is the simplest one. It works everywhere and its values are lost upon page reload or when the process is killed."

Comment: Maintainer of axios-cache-interceptor here. Both comments are right, memory storage is a simpler one and have its limitations. But the correct answer for the above question is to use async/await or thenables.